# Not getting Hive databases details inside swing UI

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, derby, cloudera-cdh

I am creating a java swing ui which will connect to Hive databases and tables and provide me the details on UI itself.

I am able to generate the UI but details of all Hive databases and tables are not comming except the **"default"** database. But inside **"default"** database also I am not able to get the tables present inside it.

**Here is the code to retrieve the Hive database**

```
HiveConf hconf = new HiveConf();  
HiveMetaStoreClient msClient = new HiveMetaStoreClient(hconf);  
List<String> dbs = msClient.getAllDatabases();  
System.out.println(All Databases: "+ dbs); //All Databases: [default]
List<String> tbls = msClient.getAllTables(dbName);  
System.out.println(All Tables: "+ tbls); // All Tables: []
```

**System details**
Hadoop distribution: Cloudera Quickstart VM on Windows
version: CDH5.4.2

**My hive-site.xml looks like this**

```
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
<description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hive</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>cloudera</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name>
    <value>/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hwi-0.8.1-cdh4.0.0.jar</value>
    <description>This is the WAR file with the jsp content for Hive Web Interface</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://127.0.0.1:9083</value>
    <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**My thought**
In the process to solve this issue, I sysout hive conf properties

```
System.out.println("All Hive conf property: "+ hconf.getAllProperties().toString());
```

I found some properties where it uses derby database, I don't know from where it is using derby database

**here are some output of hive conf properties when I sysout it**

```
hive.stats.dbconnectionstring=jdbc:derby:;databaseName=TempStatsStore;  
hive.stats.jdbcdriver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver  
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true,  
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver,
```

From the output it looks it is connecting to derby database, but I am not getting why it is connecting to derby database, since in my **hive-site.xml** It is mentioned mysql database.

Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue. Need to add hive conf as external class folder in your build path.

**Right click on you project in eclipse -- Build Path -- Configure Build Path -- Java Build Path -- Libraries --  Add External Class Folder -- select the conf folder (/usr/lib/hive/conf) -- OK -- OK**

All done. Now I am able to get my hive databases and tables.